# Jetty: JSP support not configured

Tags: jetty, shrinkwrap

***What I have:***

I start my jetty server with help of Shrinkwrap tool.

***What a problem:***

The problem is *500 JSP support not configured* exception.

***What a question:***

I've read that to solve the problem you should start app with command `java -jar start.jar OPTIONS=Server,jsp`

But I repeat that I use shrinkwrap to package and start my application from *.war archive.

***How should I pass OPTIONS=Server,jsp optin to ShrinkWrap server?***